# " escape sequence in C?

Tags: c, string

What is the escape sequence for ' " ' in C? In other words, how can i ask a while-statement to search for an occurance of ' " '?

Comment: To clarify: given a `char*` you want to stop when you find a double quote?

Answer (score 11):

In a character constant, you don't need to escape the `"` character; you can simply use `'"'`.

In a string literal, you do need to escape the `"` character since it's the delimiter; you do this by prefixing it with a backslash (`"\""`).

Note that you can escape the `"` character in a character constant (`'\"'`); it's just not necessary.

Comment: You could also use `\x22` in place of `\"` to search for a double-quote in a string

Comment: @Zabba:  If I saw `\x22` in a code review, I'd almost assuredly consider it [a major code WTF](http://28.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_kpu8502s7I1qa3ti5o1_400.jpg).

Answer (score 1):

You want to look for `"\""`

Answer (score 1):

Use `strchr()` from `string.h`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
      char str[] = "This is a sample string with \" another \"";
      char * pch;
      printf ("Looking for the '\"' character in: %s ...\n",str);
      pch=strchr(str,'"');
      while (pch!=NULL)
      {
            printf ("found at %d\n",pch-str+1);
            pch=strchr(pch+1,'\"');
      }
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: you really don't need to use string.h for this.  `while(*pch++ != '"' && *pch);` moves `pch` to the first position of a double quote or until the end of the string.

Comment: But `strchr` might be several times faster with large strings, due to the ability to search whole words (or whole 16-byte chunks with sse, etc.) at a time.

Comment: The flip side is that `strchr` loses the information about the length of the string if the character was not found, so you have to waste `O(n)` time calling `strlen` to find it again if you needed it. An alternative would be `strcspn`, but it's likely not to be optimized for the case of a single character set.

Answer (score 0):

The character `'"'`, ASCII code 34. `"In a string literal you escape it like \" this"`.